# Swift Type Erasure with Generic Enum and Generic Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2, swift-protocols

I have had to use type erasure in Swift a few times however it always involved a generic protocol.  In this case, it involves both a generic enum **and** and generic protocol and I'm stumped.

Here is my generic enum and generic protocol with the necessary extension:

```
enum UIState<T> {
    case Loading
    case Success([T])
    case Failure(ErrorType)
}

protocol ModelsDelegate: class {
    associatedtype Model
    var state: UIState<[Model]> { get set }
}

extension ModelsDelegate {

    func getNewState(state: UIState<[Model]>) -> UIState<[Model]> {
        return state
    }

    func setNewState(models: UIState<[Model]>) {
        state = models
    }
}
```

And here is my type erased generic class:

```
class AnyModelsDelegate<T>: ModelsDelegate {
    var state: UIState<[T]> {

        get { return _getNewState(UIState<[T]>) }  // Error #1
        set { _setNewState(newValue) }
    }

    private let _getNewState: ((UIState<[T]>) -> UIState<[T]>)
    private let _setNewState: (UIState<[T]> -> Void)

    required init<U: ModelsDelegate where U.Model == T>(_ models: U) {
        _getNewState = models.getNewState
        _setNewState = models.setNewState
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors (they are marked in the code sample):

Error #1:

`Cannot convert value of type '(UIState<[T]>).Type' (aka 'UIState<Array<T>>.Type') to expected argument type 'UIState<[_]>' (aka 'UIState<Array<_>>')`

I have been working on this for awhile and there have been quite a few variations on this code that "almost worked".  The error *always* has to do with the getter.

Comment: You're passing a type to a method that takes an instance of that type

Comment: I'm a little confused why your `getNewState` function takes an input, surely it should be a `() -> UIState<[Model]>`? Although if your `getNewState` and `setNewState` functions solely exist to forward the getting and setting to your type erasure, they aren't necessary, as you could do this directly in the type erasure with closures (i.e `_getNewState = { models.state }` & `_setNewState = { models.state = $0 }`).

Comment: Yes I am a bit confused about that as well :).  It takes an input because originally I was getting errors when it did not take an input.  Let me try to refactor.

Comment: Thank you, that was it.  Please post your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that causes this error, as [@dan has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922319/swift-type-erasure-with-generic-enum-and-generic-protocol#comment65201537_38922319), is that on this line you're trying to pass a type as an argument, instead of an instance of that type:

```
get { return _getNewState(UIState<[T]>) }
```

However, I would question your use of an argument to this function in the first place, surely a getting function should have no argument at all? In this case you'll simply want your `_getNewState` function to have the signature `() -> UIState<[T]>`, and call it like so:

```
get { return _getNewState() }
```

Also, if your `getNewState` and `setNewState(_:)` functions in your protocol extension only exist in order to forward the getting and setting of your `state` property to the type-erasure – you can simplify your code by getting rid of them entirely and use closure expressions in the type-erasure's `init` instead:

```
_getNewState = { models.state }
_setNewState = { models.state = $0 }
```

<sup>(These work by capturing a reference to the `models` argument, for more info see [Closures: Capturing Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103))</sup>

Finally, I suspect that you mean to refer to `UIState<T>` rather than `UIState<[T]>` throughout your code, as `T` in this case refers to an element in the array that your `.Success` case has as an associated value (unless you want  a 2D array here).

All in all, with the above proposed changes, you'll want your code to look something like this:

```
enum UIState<T> {
    case Loading
    case Success([T])
    case Failure(ErrorType)
}

protocol ModelsDelegate: class {
    associatedtype Model
    var state: UIState<Model> { get set }
}

class AnyModelsDelegate<T>: ModelsDelegate {
    var state: UIState<T> {
        get { return _getNewState() }
        set { _setNewState(newValue) }
    }

    private let _getNewState: () -> UIState<T>
    private let _setNewState: (UIState<T>) -> Void

    required init<U: ModelsDelegate where U.Model == T>(_ models: U) {
        _getNewState = { models.state }
        _setNewState = { models.state = $0 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  And yes, I did not want a 2D array.  That was a mistake on my part as I was trying to work through the errors.

Comment: @damianesteban Happy to help :)